# WPF Change ListView Content (ContentPresenter) highlight color

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

How to change background color of content in listview while mouse is over, when content represents "ContentPresenter".

```
 <ListView Visibility="{Binding ListViewVisibility}" Style="{StaticResource MenuListViewStyle}">
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Item, ElementName=menuButton}"/>
    </ListView>
```

I want to change this blue background to be transparent, it looks like this: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MauL4.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize it by using listview **ItemContainerStyle**.

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                            <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="Transparent"  Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#70C0E7" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```